# what does p stand for in scaleAt(a, b, p) in DOJO framwork?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am new to this DOJO javascript framework.
I am facing problem with using for scaling circle its not working.

```
objectShape.applyTransform(gfx.matrix.scaleAt(xx, yy, p));
```

for some cases its working fine for rectangle but after some conditions/changes in shape its not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter p is a 2D point around which the scale is performed. That point is the center of the scale operation. So, in this case, you're scaling xx, yy around p.x, p.y.

You have probably already looked at the documentation, but just in case you haven't, here are some links:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/gfx-geometric-properties.html#scaleat

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/gfx#transformations-around-a-point